# How to send messages on things-network using Jquery REST API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

[image]I have a device and I am testing my button to see if it receives messages on **things network**.

I have following request. But I am testing when it is on for now and need some guidance as I am new on this platform: I saw while researching this link, i dont know if it is relevant, please help mates  HTTP 404 Not found.

- deviceId
- payload_raw
- url

Html:

```
<!-----Toggle switch button On/Off.  --->
<div class = "wrapper" align = "center">
  <div class="btn-group" id="toggle_event_editing">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger locked_active">OFF</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success unlocked_inactive">ON</button>
  </div> 
  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="switch_status">Switched off.</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

I have tried used the crossDomain logic from the Jquery Documentation, below; The error still persist, what could be an issue now?

```
$.ajax({
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://integrations.thethingsnetwork.org/ttn-eu/api/v2/down/acts083_test/mkr1300?key=ttn-account-v2.7Ph6lBffU7wI9cLY5ljIhIb_I7sqH5EVvo5zs9uVyA0""
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

// XMLHttpRequest
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://integrations.thethingsnetwork.org/ttn-eu/api/v2/down/acts083_test/mkr1300?key=ttn-account-v2.7Ph6lBffU7wI9cLY5ljIhIb_I7sqH5EVvo5zs9uVyA0"", true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();

// Fetch with credentials
fetch("https://integrations.thethingsnetwork.org/ttn-eu/api/v2/down/acts083_test/mkr1300?key=ttn-account-v2.7Ph6lBffU7wI9cLY5ljIhIb_I7sqH5EVvo5zs9uVyA0"", {
    credentials: "include"
}).then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

Comment: please explain exactly what you want / expect this code to do, and also what it currently does when you run it. It's unclear what the specific issue is.

Comment: I have a button that switch on/off to my thingspeak channel. The Url for things network must be able to do the same, with its payload being AAA = decodes to 0000(0ff) button and payload being AAE= decodes to 0001(on) button when its switch on. I hope making some sense a bit, i am new to things network to do this.

Comment: Ok. That's useful background information about the general purpose of your code. But it doesn't actually answer my question. We still don't know what specific issue you are experiencing.

Comment: My button suppose to do a post method to my things network, to receive message. That is my issue, currently i does not receive any message on things network.

Comment: Ok. But there could  be lots of reasons for that. It's just a symptom. You need to start investigating. We can't investigate, because we can't run your code. What debugging have you done? Does something go wrong in the code shown, so that a message does not get sent to the server? Do you see errors in your browser'S Console or Network tools? Is there some other unexpected behaviour? It's still unclear. We can't fix any code if you can't explain what happens when you execute it.

Comment: I have attached the issue, please find it as an image png

Comment: Ok. So do you understand what Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for more info. Basically, the error means that server is not allowing you to make AJAX requests to it. If you control the server, you can amend it to enable CORS for the domain where you're making the AJAX request from. If it's not your server, speak to the maintainers. If it's some kind of public API or SaaS application, they may have a scheme where you can register your website to allow CORS requests from it (Google do this for their APIs, for example).

Comment: P.S. If you put your error message into a search engine you'll also get a huge amount of existing information about it.

Comment: What happened if i add extra argument on my Ajax call e.g crossDomain:true, DateFormat:jsonp?

Comment: The best way to know that is to try, don't you think. I doubt either will help necessarily - ultimately it's the server's decision if they want to allow your request or not. You can read the jQuery $.ajax documentation to see what the "crossDomain" setting actually does in practice. JSONP will not help you unless the server actually returns data in JSONP format. I would assume you can discover that easily from their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you have are due to CORS (Cross Origin Request Sharing). It's a protection on your browser activated when you do POST requests on domain that is different from your page.

[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

The possible options:

- Try to test GET post first,
- Try with another browser (Chrome is
  picky about this).

For your request to work, you should have the following headers in the server response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://toto.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

And you have the server to support preflight OPTIONS queries.

Comment: well i am using thingspeak channel, it has javascript plugin. where will i have to put these headers? i was trying to use rest client by invoking the PUT method. There was getting 404 not found responce. Im still getting no luck here mates.

Comment: It's on the server-side, maybe there is a thingspeak documentation about it. On one side, are you supposed to use a browser and JQuery to post ? It's rather a IoT direct REST query, no ?

Comment: browser and Jquery post